# Can not access MUI components, React-Router throws an error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router

I am using MUI components for my app. I have the following packages installed:

```
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.6",
```

For some reason, I keep getting the error below:

`React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'duration') - at Drawer2`;
when accessing MUI components like Drawer and AppBar.

I am using vite.

Comment: `react-router` hasn't much of anything to do with Material-UI components. Since we can't really address issues in code we can't see can you [edit] to include the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace, and a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

React Router errorElement handles errors thrown by the application while rendering, loading data, or performing data mutations. React Router will catch this error and show the error screen.
For MUI components like the Drawer, during render, an error will be thrown if the `theme.transitions.duration` (default), is not included in the theme, or set in the `transitionDuration` prop of the element.

```
const Drawer = /*#__PURE__*/React.forwardRef(function Drawer(inProps, ref) {
  const props = useThemeProps({
    props: inProps,
    name: 'MuiDrawer'
  });
  const theme = useTheme();
  const defaultTransitionDuration = {
    enter: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    exit: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
  };
```